# Clear range selected in Excel listbox and delete range name

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a listbox in a userform module. When shown, it contains three range names. Let's call them Range1, Range2, and Range3. When the user clicks on one, I want the corresponding range to be cleared and the range name to be deleted.

Thanks to anyone who can advise me on the code to do this.

Comment: Write an event handler for the click event for the listbox control. Establish a reference to the range corresponding to the selected name and then clear the range using the range's  `.Clear` or `ClearContents` method. Remove the name from the listbox's list using the `RemoveItem` method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment.But I think this link will help you.

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=83396

Answer (score 0):

I actually deleted the range.  Alternatively, you could use `Range(.Value).ClearContents` to clear only the data or `Range(.Value).Clear` to clear the data and formatting from the range.

[image]

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    With ListBox1
        If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Range(.Value).Delete
            ThisWorkbook.Names(.Value).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End With
    RefreshRangeList
End Sub

Sub RefreshRangeList()
    Dim n As Name
    ListBox1.Clear
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        ListBox1.AddItem n.Name
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    RefreshRangeList
End Sub
```